# Can one force the screen resolution which is used to select resources?

Tags: android, resources, screen-resolution

In our Android we use different layouts for different screen resolutions, using the resource selection mechanism described at

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

This works great, except for some devices which report the wrong screen size.

In particular we would want to use the same resolution on the Kindle Fire and the Nook Tablet. These have 600x1024 screens and thus should report themselves as having "large" screens. The Kindle Fire does so, but the Nook Tablets picks the "xlarge" resources:

http://nookdeveloper.zendesk.com/entries/20814001-emulator-loads-xlarge-layout

I can detect that the application is running on a Nook Tablet, and add a special case for it, but I have not found how I can force the resource selection mechanism to pick up resources for a certain screen size.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution (that you're probably not looking for) would be to not have an XLarge set of resources available for the Nook release.  This causes both Nook devices to load the same resources.  That's what I did, but since I didn't have a great set of XLarge changes this wasn't a big deal for me.

Sadly, Android didn't fix this issue until 3.2, which has minimum width selectors rather than the old bucket system.  Nook is hanging tight at 2.3.4, though, so you'll need to roll your own if you want a better size selection system.

Personally, I haven't targeted 10" tablets as much as 7" tablets, because the top sellers are currently the Kindle Fire and Nook devices. The high profile of Nook may make it worth creating a separate build.